# python aws sdk is missing transcribe streaming API

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-transcribe

I checked github code for transcribe streaming options and it looks like there is no transcribe streaming mentions neither in docs nor in config file: `src/botocore/botocore/data/transcribe/2017-10-26/service-2.json`.

But I see documentation for Ruby: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/TranscribeStreamingService.html
This is why I believe it makes sense to do it using scripting (not compiled) language.

Are there any plans to add it in the future? If yes, when approximately?
Or am I simply missing it?

I saw documentation describes low level communication for this kind of API, but I want to save dev time re-using the lib.

Answer (score 0):

python sdk for transcribe streaming is not available yet.